# selecting amountofpersons where date and separated time is compared with sql date/separated time C#

Tags: c#, sql, date, time, datetimepicker

```
connect.Open();
dtpTime.CustomFormat = "H:mm";
dtpDate.CustomFormat = "M/d/yyy";

int plaatsen=50;
int personennu=0;

dbreader = null;
dbcommand = new OleDbCommand("SELECT aantalpersonen FROM bestelling WHERE datum="+dtpDate.Text+" ", connect);

dbreader = dbcommand.ExecuteReader();
while (dbreader.Read())
{
    personennu = personennu + Convert.ToInt32(dbreader.GetValue(0));
}
if (personennu < plaatsen)
{
    lblPersonen.Text = (plaatsen - personennu).ToString();
}
else 
{
    lblPersonen.Text = "unavailable"; 
}
connect.Close();
```

I am trying to compare a date time picker and a sql (oledb) so I can get the amount of persons back from my table (aantalpersonen in dutch). It has to compare the day and the hour so if one is starting at 11/18/2010 at 9'o clock and I compare it with one of 10 o'clock it should give me the places (plaatsen in dutch) back, but if there aren't places left (more than 50 places) then it should say unavailable, but I can't seem to get the time date of c# with the time and date of sql correct it gives me all the time 50 now.

Comment: note that if i remove the WHERE statement (so all what there is) there is no problem with the code so it is in the date part (the conversation between sql/db acces to c# ) do note also that i set the type of my acces database to datetime with a short date dont know if that is any of importment but just that you gues know

Comment: got it working dbcommand = new OleDbCommand("SELECT aantalpersonen FROM bestelling WHERE datum=@mydate ", connect);
            OleDbParameter myParam = new OleDbParameter();
            myParam.ParameterName = "@mydate";
            myParam.OleDbType = OleDbType.DBDate;
            myParam.Value = dtpDate.Value;
            MessageBox.Show(myParam.Value.ToString());
            dbcommand.Parameters.Add(myParam);

Comment: Instead of posting your answer in a comment, you should post it as an answer and accept it.

Comment: Thnx for the comment, fixed it now lars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got it working

```
dbcommand = new OleDbCommand("SELECT aantalpersonen FROM bestelling WHERE datum=@mydate ",connect); 
OleDbParameter myParam = new OleDbParameter();
myParam.ParameterName = "@mydate"; 
myParam.OleDbType = OleDbType.DBDate; 
myParam.Value = dtpDate.Value; 
MessageBox.Show(myParam.Value.ToString()); 
dbcommand.Parameters.Add(myParam);
```